# Sitecore Items - Programmatically test if anonymous user has permission

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8, user-permissions

I'm trying to test if items can be viewed by an anonymous user:

```
var anon = User.FromName("domain\\Anonymous");

if (item.Security.CanRead(anonymousUser))
    return true;
```

But it always returns true, even when I know that for particular items, they must have a certain role to view it, as I can see from the access viewer:

[image]

Comment: Where should the item be visible? Is the item a page to be viewed in a browser? Or an item in the content tree? Which revision of sitecore 8?

Comment: It's a page to be viewed. It's `Sitecore 81 rev 160302`

Comment: Just to add context, this code is in a computed field for an index. I need to only get results that the user has permission for. I know Sitecore has a `SearchSecurityOptions.EnableSecurityCheck` mechanism, but to be honest its a bit of a joke as it doesn't respect the `TotalSearchResults` property and breaks paging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The responsible crawler -which actually executes ComputeFieldValue code- is designed in such way to wrap this code in a **SecurityDisabler**. That is why it is not possible inside a computed field to verify whether has access to the field or not.

Sitecore does recommend to do the security check during the search (ootb) but indeed the TotalResults do not match if you do - which sucks ;)

If you would try to get security in the index - first try to find a solution for keeping the item security updated. E.g. if you would break inheritance somewhere, how would your index know what items to update? ...

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. I think I've figured out a way of getting what I need by indexing the access rules for the items.

Comment: Hey @DavidMasters, I know it has been a while since you had this issue, but I wonder if you can post some tips about how you indexed the access rules for the items